# Why is sarcoma more prevalent and common in right heart?

Tags: cardiology, pathophysiology, cancer

Ewing's sarcoma or Ewing sarcoma is a malignant small, round, blue cell tumor. It is a rare disease in which cancer cells are found in the bone or in soft tissue. It is more common in right heart than left heart? Why? Which one is more dangerous?

Answer (score 8):

Ewing's sarcoma is a [**bone** cancer](http://www.webmd.com/cancer/ewings-sarcoma). As such, it does not arise as a primary tumor in the heart.

Ewing's sarcoma does metastasize. Like any metastatic cancer, it seeds along it's venous return to the heart, "taking root" in suitable tissue.

Cardiac metastases of Ewing's sarcoma are exceedingly rare, with only a few reported cases. Since all blood returns to the right side of the heart first, then the lungs, this is where distant metastases of Ewing's sarcoma are found. The side doesn't matter; it's never good.

Primary heart tumors do occur, about 1/20th as often as metastatic tumors. Of these, myxomas are the most common. Of sarcomatous types, which are very rare, they can occur anywhere.

<sub>[Ewing's Sarcoma](http://www.webmd.com/cancer/ewings-sarcoma)</sub>
<sub>[Metastatic Ewing's Sarcoma to the Right Ventricle](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3232596/)</sub>
<sub>[Primary Malignant Sarcomas of the Heart and Great Vessels in Adult Patients — A Single-Center Experience](https://theoncologist.alphamedpress.org/content/12/9/1134.full)</sub>
<sub>[Echocardiographic and pathologic characteristics of primary cardiac tumors: a study of 149 cases](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167527302001365)</sub>
<sub>[Primary cardiac sarcomas: an immunohistochemical and grading study with long-term follow-up of 24 cases](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1365-2559.1999.00636.x/abstract)</sub>

Comment: About 39.9 percent of reported heart tumor is related to sarcoma tumor and this a dangerous tumor which attacks Pericardial space and block heat valves and vena cava.

Comment: @Majid - The most common tumors in the heart are metastatic. They are [20 times more common than primary neoplasms](http://heart.bmj.com/content/85/2/218.short). Of primary neoplasms, at least 50% are myxomas. That leaves a small number. In one study of [*primary neoplasms*](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S0066-782X2001000300006&script=sci_arttext) the findings were as follows: myxoma (84%), fibroma (4%), lipoma (2%), rhabdomyosarcoma (2%), hemangioma (2%), **sarcoma (2%)**, angiosarcoma (2%), and lymphoma (2%). If you have a reference, I'd be happy to read it.

Comment: Can you add references? I'm reporting this from Harrison Internal Medical book.

Comment: @Majid - those smaller titles in blue at the bottom of my answer are the references. My guess, if you're reading this in Harrison's, is that you're misunderstanding what you're reading. Harrison's isn't known for being frequently in error (that I know of). I can't check this, as my Harrison's is decades old and I donated it. Same for Cecil's, etc. All pretty much outdated and gone to a new home.